# How do I use Group By and MAX in Linq to return multiple rows?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

**Clarified example**
I have a database of users that is created by a script that scans through Active Directory. One of the fields it applies is a "ScanDate" field, which indicates when the scan took place. The script scans through multiple Active Directory domains.

GOAL: Obtain an IList from the database that contains the list of users for ALL domains, but where the ScanDate is the MAX(ScanDate) for each domain.

This ensures I get the freshest data for each domain.

A SQL query that appears to work for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM ADScans a
WHERE a.ScanDate = (SELECT MAX(b.ScanDate) FROM ADScans b WHERE a.Domain = b.Domain) AND Enabled = 1
```

However, having trouble getting that expressed in LINQ

<strike>e.g.:</strike>

Category | Date

Cat1       4/4/16

Cat2     | 4/4/16

Cat3     | 4/4/16

Cat1     | 4/3/16

I would expect a list:

Cat1 | 4/4/16

Cat2 | 4/4/16

Cat3 | 4/4/16

**Some clarification**

I would expect to have multiple rows returned per category - the MAX(Date) will not just give me one.  I am looking to obtain ALL of the rows for the MAX(Date) of each category.

Comment: Your question is no longer clear. If you get multiple rows for each category that has the same date, then these items are duplicates of each other. Is this what you want? Please give a better example.

Answer (score 0):

You can `GroupBy` by `Domain` to get the max `ScanDate`, then keep only the rows with that Date.

For a model like this:

```
class ADScan
{
    public int Domain { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScanDate { get; set; }
}
```

You can get the scans doing this:

```
var result = scans.GroupBy(s => s.Domain)
                  .SelectMany(g => g.Where(s => s.ScanDate == g.Max(d => d.ScanDate)));
```

This produces a collection containing the scans with the max `ScanDate` for its `Domain`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var result =
    list
    //Group by Category
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    //For each Category, select Category and max Date within the Category
    //This would create an anonymous object, you could do a "new Entity" instead if you want
    .Select(g => new {Category = g.Key, Date = g.Max(x => x.Date)}) 
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

```
from u in this.db.ADScans
where u.ScanDate == 
    (from s in this.db.ADScans where u.Domain == s.Domain select s.ScanDate).Max() 
    && u.Enabled
select u;
```

Comment: While this might work, I believe it will be less efficient than ordering grouped items and selecting the top from each. You may want to test performance before going this route.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking at it, this approach is incorrect unless you can guarantee that the `ScanDate` values are all unique. If two ADScans have the same ScanDate, and one of them is the most recent for its domain, your query will return both, even if the other one is on a different domain.

Comment: I would want both.  I consider a unique entry to be Domain+ScanDate+Username.  This way I can get the latest list of all unique user accounts in each domain

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Max()`, just order the items in the groups and take the top item: since you ordered the items, it's guaranteed to be the highest one:

```
var mostRecentScanFromEachDomain =
    from u in this.db.ADScans
    where u.Enabled
    group u by u.Domain into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(u => u.ScanDate)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```